# Read active Word document Stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I would like to get my whole active Word document as base64 and I already have this Code:

```
var doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
return System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString()));
```

But data is always null

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why Base64? This isn't really a format that Word supports...

Comment: I would like to upload the file via an API which requires base64. But the problem occurs earlier. The variable data is null.

Comment: Can you convert XML content directly to Base64? doc.ActiveDocument.Content.WordOpenXML (or doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range.WordOpenXML) will return the full representation of the document in the OPC flat file format. This allows you to recreate the document at a later point...